# Including scripts in sections in MVC EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fine-uploader

I created an editor template for FineUploader doing the following:

```
    @model String
    @using System.Web.Mvc;

    @{
        var controlId = Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(String.Empty);
        var uploaderId = (Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(String.Empty) + "-" + "uploader");
        var kValue = Model;
    }

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    @if(kValue == null || kValue == "")
    {
        <div class="blue">
            <img src="/Images/profilepics/blank-person.jpg" title="No Picture" id="@(controlId + "-pic")" />
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="blue">
            <img src="@kValue"  />
        </div>
    }
        <div id="@uploaderId"></div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                    element: document.getElementById('@uploaderId'),
                    request: {
                        endpoint: '/Uploads/ImageUpload/',
                        params: {
                            UploadType: '@controlId',
                            RelatedId: '@ViewData["kuser"]'
                        }
                    },
                    multiple: false,
                    text: {
                        uploadButton: '<div><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>Change picture</div>'
                    },
                    template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                                '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-success" style="width: auto;  margin-top: 10px;">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                                '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                                '<ul class="qq-upload-list" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;"></ul>' +
                              '</div>',
                    classes: {
                        success: 'alert alert-success',
                        fail: 'alert alert-error'
                    },
                    callbacks: {
                        onComplete: function (id, name, response) {
                            var img = document.getElementById("@(controlId + "-pic")");
                            img.src = response.path;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

This works fine... but what I'd like to do is in the template do the following:

```
@section head {

    @Styles.Render("~/uploaderCss")
    @Scripts.Render("~/uploaderJs")
}
```

However, it appears that when including the Script.Render and Styles.Render in the head / script section they do not render.  And if I link them directly, if there are more than one uploader controller on the page, the script will attempt to load twice... is there a way to include script references in the EditorTemplate so that the parent page knows the scripts are already loaded?  As a work around, I had to include the scripts on the parent page, but that really isn't optimal because I'll need to remember to put them on the page anytime I end up using an ImagePath EditorFor...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18109597/1783240

Comment: thanks for your help Stephen, that worked masterfully...